# startup script in freebsd is not running

Tags: shell, freebsd

I have been trying to run a shell script at boot time of freebsd. I have read all simmilar questions in stackoverflow and tried. But nothing is worked. This is the sample code that i tried is `dummy`.

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/rc.subr
name="dummy"
start_cmd="${name}_start"
stop_cmd=":"

dummy_start()
{
    echo "Nothing started."
}

load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

Saved with name of `dummy`.
Permissions are `-r-xr-xr-x`.
in rc.conf file made `dummy_enable="YES"`.

The problem is, when i rebooted my system to test, `dummy` file is not there. So script is not executing. what else need to do run my dummy script.

SRC:`http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/rc-scripting/article.html#rc-flags`

Comment: in which directory did you store your "dummy" file?

Comment: @LtWorf : I placed dummy in /etc/rc.d/ folder

Comment: Then it doesn't really make any sense that it gets removed at reboot...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `rcvar="dummy_enable"` to your script. At least for FreeBSD 9.1.

Call your script with parameter `rcvar` to get the enabled status:

```
# /etc/rc.d/dummy rcvar
# dummy
#
dummy_enable="YES"
#   (default: "")
```

And finally start it with parameter `start` - this won't start the service/script unless `dummy_enable` is set in `/etc/rc.conf` (or `/etc/rc.conf.local`, or `/etc/defaults/rc.conf`)

```
# /etc/rc.d/dummy start
Nothing started.
```

Comment: I followed the above procedure. It is working only when i run script manually by `/etc/rc.d/dummy start` command. But my script should start at boot time, when i reboot the dummy file is getting removed and so script is also not running. Why?

Comment: @Kranthi The dummy file (/etc/rc.d/dummy?) is getting removed? I am pretty sure that nothing in a standard installation will remove anything from /etc/rc.d during a system boot. Do you have any other custom startup scripts or local modifications?

Comment: @Kranthi By the way: `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` would be a better place for a custom script. `/etc/rc.d` is for the base system.

Comment: There is no `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` directory in my system.

Comment: @Kranthi It shall be there. What system are you running on? Is there something messed up with your system? All startup scripts for software installed from packages/ports are installed in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d`.

Comment: Can't we run script from /etc/rc.d?

Comment: @Kranthi Yes, you can. The startup script treats both directory (almost) identical. But `/etc/rc.d` is for the base system. `mergemaster` will give you warnings if you have extra files in there. I would assume `freebsd-update` would do the same. But there seems to be something seriously flawed with your system. Either fix it or try (somewhere else) on a clean install. Nobody can help you if you have non-standard custom modifications which nobody knows about.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that **rcorder(8)** says:

> Within each file, a block containing a series of "REQUIRE", "PROVIDE",
>   "BEFORE" and "KEYWORD" lines must appear.

Though elsewhere I recall that if a file doesn't have "REQUIRE", "PROVIDE" or "BEFORE", then it will be arbitrarily placed in the dependency ordering.  And, it could be that the arbitrary placement differs between the first run up to $early_late_divider and in the second run of those after $early_late_divider.

OTOH, is this a stock FreeBSD, or some variant?  I recall reading that FreeNAS saves its configuration somewhere else and recreates its system files on every boot.  And, quite possibly that /etc is actually on a ramdisk.

Also, `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` doesn't come into existence until the first port installing an rc file is installed.